# Which is faster: if (var == 'value' ) OR if (/value/.test(var))

Tags: javascript, performance

Which is faster:

```
if (var == 'value')
```

or

```
if (/value/.test(var))
```

Comment: Instead of asking which one is faster, you should consider which one is clearer, more obvious, and correct (I assume there's some difference for non-string values).

Comment: Those two operations don't do the same thing. Pick the one that's appropriate for the task, and don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Look at that http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-string-equals/2 :-)

Comment: @delnan I disagree, especially for client side code where hardware is out of your control or prediction, code efficiency is paramount, clarity can be gained by comments, the UX is of ultimate importance in my book.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, that only matters if you can ***prove*** the code is below the efficiency threshold. You need to analyze the code to find bottlenecks, not just pick a line at random.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: But regardless of how feeble the client hardware may be, the majority of the code never dominates runtime. There's no indication that OP's snippet is in a tight loop, and if it is, there may be a better way to do it anyway. It's only worth optimizing if you can *prove* optimizing it changes anything at all, and you better have a good reason to think it's too slow for your clients. Otherwise, it's a waste of time and there are far better opportunities to improve UX.

Comment: @zzzzBov That sounds like a straw man, how could you ever prove a bottleneck when your code is running in an unpredictable environment? all you can do is write the most efficient code possible, sure you should focus on getting the most bang for your buck, but to generally say that performance should yield to code clarity, is a mistake in my opinion.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, if you measure the performance of your code and you find that function `a` takes `~1ms` and function `b` takes `300ms`, you should focus on function `b`. That's what I'm saying. Measurement comes before optimization.

Comment: @zzzzBov but learning these optimizations and eventually writing it that way the first time, pre-measurement, is the key.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, I used to think that way, but I've found that writing *readable* code has been more important toward overall code performance than micro-optimization. I'm not saying I don't pay attention to responsiveness of design, I just don't care about the difference between a `1ms` operation and a `0.8ms` operation. Neither will hold up the UI in any noticeable way. `++a;` is more responsive than `a++;` is more responsive than `a+=1;` for incrementing a variable by one, however I still write `a++` out of habit in my `for` loops, and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (a == 'b')` will be faster than `if (/b/.test(a))`, but they're not identical calls.

`'something' == 'some'` is `false`, whereas `/some/.test('something')` is `true`.

The only reason to change from one to the other would be if the other's more appropriate. If you're worried about speed, benchmark your script and check where the bottlenecks are before worrying about a specific `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you all! The comments and replies helped tremendously.

Answer (score 8):

`if(var == 'value')`.  By a lot.  But if you really want fast, do `if(var === 'value')`.  Strict equivalency has a lot less work to do than type-coerced equivalency.

Comment: But `===` is more strict than `==`, so it isn't really a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @Blender: It's much closer to equivalent than the two things the OP specified.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: `22%` is pretty significant, if you ask me.

Comment: @Blender: It's a regex comparison that is actually testing whether the string 'value' *occurs* in the contents of `var`.  So it's barely in the neighborhood.  (And its performance best-case is looking at every character in `var` to see whether it's 'v' and finding no positives.)  @jondavidjohn: I don't know what metric you're using, but several times the operation count is "a lot" to my way of thinking.

Comment: @Blender I guess it depends on your browser, I'm seeing it much closer in the cumulative results.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: For extra fun, try varying the contents of `var`, particularly with some long values.  (And non-string values, if you're testing `==` vs. `===`.  As far as I can tell, they're equivalent on all significant JS engines if the comparands are always the same type.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a Huge speed difference, but the former is definitely more readable and makes more sense...

http://jsperf.com/string-vs-regex-test/2

Comment: That test isn't totally appropriate to the OP's case (even if we presume that he meant `/^value$/.test(var)`).  Equivalency does poorly because the test is of case-insensitive comparison, so tests that are nominally of `==` and `===` are actually absorbing the (rather heavy) cost of `toLowerCase()`.